# python как одновременно запустить несколько потоков в каждом из которых есть бесконечный цикл?

Tags: python, многопоточность

Помогите найти решение. Я хочу запустить количество потоков равное количеству элементов в списке. Проблема заключается в том, что в классе у меня содержится цикл while True, отказаться от которого я не могу, и сталкиваюсь с ситуацией при которой программа  логично останавливается первый раз натолкнувшись на while True и я получаю на вывод :1,1,1,1... Но мне необходимо, что бы в данный момент времени были запущены все потоки(т.е. столько потоков сколько элементов в списке, в каждом из который будет исполнятся свой независящий ни от кого while True), как мне этого достичь ??
мой код:

```
import threading

a=[1,2]
empty_list=[]
class test():
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.i=i
        self.while_true()

    def while_true(self):
        while True:
            print(self.i)

for i in range (len(a)):
    empty_list.append(a[i])

for i in range (len(empty_list)):
    empty_list[i]=threading.Thread(target=test(a[i]))
    empty_list[i].start()
```

Comment: @insolor можно Вас попросить расписать поподробней, не совсем понятно.

Comment: @insolor есть же args отдельным параметром.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В параметре `target` нужно передавать ссылку на функцию (без скобок) или в вашем случае класс (опять же, без скобок), а вы сразу создаете объект, из-за чего сразу стартует бесконечный цикл в основном потоке. Рабочий вариант:

```
empty_list[i]=threading.Thread(target=test, args=(a[i],))
```

Через параметр `args` передается кортеж с позиционными параметрами, которые будут переданы в `test` при создании объекта. Подробнее см. [документацию по Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread).

---

Еще один вариант - реализовать класс с методом `__call__` (тогда объект класса можно будет вызывать как функцию):

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.i=i

    def __call__(self)
        while True:
            print(self.i)

...

empty_list[i]=threading.Thread(target=Test(a[i]))
```

В этом случае будет создан объект класса, инициализированный нужными параметрами (без старта цикла), передан в `Thread`, а при создании потока этот объект будет вызван как функция - тогда уже будет вызван метод `__call__` созданного объекта, и стартует бесконечный цикл.

Оба варианта с отдельным классом избыточны (излишне усложнены), вместо класса достаточно было создать функцию `test`, и передать ее `Thread` по первому варианту (с передачей параметров через `args`).